# When should I give an SQL table its own numeric primary key?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have a general content management system where I keep a table of nodes (navigation points that have associated permissions), and a table for each kind of node (blog post, comment, attachment, etc).

My node tables (in MySQL) look like so:

```
CREATE TABLE node_types (
    type_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type_parent INT,
    type_name VARCHAR(31) UNIQUE KEY,

    FOREIGN KEY (type_parent) REFERENCES node_types(type_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE nodes (
    node_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type_id INT,
    parent_id INT,

    FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES node_types (type_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES nodes (node_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then to create different types of nodes I do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE attachments (
    node_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    attachment_filename VARCHAR(255),
    attachment_title VARCHAR(255),

    FOREIGN KEY (node_id) REFERENCES nodes (node_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO node_types (type_name) VALUES ('attachment');
```

Using this method I can develop a generic permissions system that applies to nodes without having to specialize it for all my different node types by referencing the node_id.

In this situation, I didn't give attachments its "own" numeric primary key because an attachment is-a node with a 1:1 relationship to a node - its primary key is based on the node_id. But some people would / do. The attachments table could be easily rewritten as:

```
CREATE TABLE attachments (
    attachment_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    node_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- a node is-a attachment.
    attachment_filename VARCHAR(255),
    attachment_title VARCHAR(255)

    FOREIGN KEY (node_id) REFERENCES nodes (node_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO node_types (type_name) VALUES ('attachment');
```

What do you think are the important reasons why or why not one would put give a numeric unique primary key ID to a table? In particular, I'm feeling that I'm sometimes inconsistent with the business of "not assigning a primary key to tables that have a 1:! is-a relationship".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a child table (i.e. a table that has a foreign key pointing to the table) you most likely want to create a primary key on the parent table.

If you have a "leaf table" it's not really necessary. However, it may be a good practice to still have one. If you still want access to it because of a website and users creating bookmarks that contain a link to a record in a leaf table, you most likely want to add a primary key here, too.

In other words, it really depends.

Comment: Why would it be good practice, btw? Is there any advantage to it if I create a primary key on attachments?

Comment: @user572491: That's why I said "it *may be* a good practice". It depends on who you talk to and what you prefer. -- Regarding the advantage: If you don't need that column in any of your logic there's no advantage, actually it consumes slightly more space. However, if at one point you have to add additional logic that requires such an id, you either have it already or you need to update your table structure accordingly, which *may* result in side effects. -- As I said, it really depends.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this will always be a 1:1 relationship your way should work.

There should not be any hard reasons to use a different uniqe id for the attachements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave it as you currently have it. Introducing an extra numeric ID seems like a recipe for confusion - if you're looking for attachment 11375, is that its attachment_id or its node_id?

As general advice, I'd recommend that you have at most one surrogate key declared on any table, and as many real keys as are actually present. A surrogate key is a numeric key (e.g. int) that's used when none of the real keys are going to be suitable for inclusion in indexes, FK references, etc, such as being a `varchar` column or (depending on exact circumstances) keys which span multiple columns.

Comment: Does the node_id on the attachment count as a surrogate key?

Comment: @user572491 - I would say yes - it's a surrogate (since it doesn't actually relate to the real world), and it's a key (since it can be used to uniquely identify a specific row in the table)